# Returning sum of specific node property values Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have the same types of nodes in a Neo4j graph. I want to return node value sums. Below is an example graph:

[image]

I want to return them in such a way that node values (`val`s) are summed w.r.t `alias` and `name` fields.

```
[
{"name": "a", "val": 120},
{"name": "b", "val": 60}
]
```

The first object summed nodes with `name` value `x`, `y`, and `a` because `x` and `y` had an alias field with value `a`.

---

Update:

Indeed, `val` property in the nodes represents number of `RELATED_TO` relationships that a node has. I wanted to abstract that for simplifying the question. The real scheme is as shown below. Every white node has several `RELATED_TO` relationships to green nodes. How can I map the number of such relationships to terminal nodes (summing `val` fields)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your update you can count the relationships summed over alias or name by

```
MATCH (n)<-[rel:RELATED_TO]-()
RETURN COALESCE(n.alias, n.name) AS name, count(rel) AS cnt
```

Answer (score 2):

this should do it

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN COALESCE(n.alias, n.name) AS name, sum(n.val) AS val
```

Comment: Thank you @Graphileon. Actually, I do not have `val` property in my nodes and I could not extend your answer to my original problem. Could please take a look at the `UPDATED` section of the question?